# Jquery Accordion not displaying properly in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, accordion

I am using this jQuery script http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion and have implemented it into my site.

It works fine in Firefox and IE but Chrome doesn't display it correctly. The the entire content div to flickers during the transition and afterwards the content div comes underneath the title divs.

I have narrowed it down to this piece of jQuery code not working correctly:

```
function openMe(id) {
        var sTitleID = id;
        var iCurrent = sTitleID.split("_")[sTitleID.split("_").length-1];
        options.currentcounter = iCurrent;
        var sContentID = id+"_msContent_"+iCurrent;
        if($("#"+sContentID).css("display")=="none") {
            if(options.previousDiv!="") {
                closeMe(options.previousDiv);
            };
            if(options.vertical) {
                $("#"+sContentID).slideDown("medium");
            } else {
                $("#"+sContentID).show(400);
                //$("#"+sContentID).css({ display: "inline" });
            }
            options.currentDiv = sContentID;
            options.previousDiv = options.currentDiv;
        };
    };
    function closeMe(div) {
        if(options.vertical) {
            $("#"+div).slideUp("medium");
        } else {
            $("#"+div).hide(400);
            //$("#"+div).css({ display: "none" });
        };
    };
```

When I replace $("#"+sContentID).show(400); with the in comment tags code $("#"+sContentID).show(400);  then the animation disaapears but it does display it correctly in all 3 browsers.

Anybody have any suggestions as to why Chrome doesn't display it correctly and how I can fix it?

Comment: could you provide us with a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo

Comment: i cant get it work in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UyeLX/

Comment: Here's a working fiddle, not sure what's going wrong though.  My only thought is that it relates in some way to the fact that both the show and hide animation are going on at the same time causing things to wrap inside the div, which causes the flashing.  Can't figure out why the content divs eventually end up below the titles though.  http://jsfiddle.net/UyeLX/1/

Comment: TY I figured out why it was putting them underneath. It had to do with the width definition on the content class in css.
   .accordionWrapper div.content {
    display:none;
    width:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:25px;
}

I created a new div to stick inside it and took away the width from .accordionWrapper div.content

It still flickers though

Comment: here is the latest version with the divs working correctly but the flickering in the animation still remaining
http://jsfiddle.net/UyeLX/3/

Comment: I found a solution. I added 2 if-statements with exceptions for the webkit browsers